# Social Authentication With CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, openid

I have a project where I'm supposed to integrate Facebook Login & Twitter Login buttons using CodeIgniter, I was wondering what would be the best approach? As this project requires more Social Login buttons in the future (like LinkedIn , Google , etc).

I heared of OpenID & JanRain.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Phil Sturgeon's Oauth/Oauth v2 Codeigniter libraries.

- https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-oauth
- https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-oauth2

Oauth v2 is the way to go. Much easier and cleaner to use. Currently it supports:

- Facebook
- Foursquare
- GitHub
- Google
- PayPal
- Instagram
- Soundcloud
- Windows Live
- YouTube

Oauth v1 is a P.I.T.A to use, but I'm afraid some popular social websites don't provide an Oauth v2 API yet

Comment: Just for reference: the project is no longer actively maintained, use https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client instead.

Answer (score 2):

Check out -

1) [HybridAuth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/)

2) [Opauth](http://opauth.org/)