# How to add social login using Hybridauth

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, shopify

how to add social login in `codeigneter`?

```
//Include Composer's autoloader
include 'vendor/autoload.php';

//Import Hybridauth's namespace
use Hybridauth\Hybridauth; 

//Now we may proceed and instantiate Hybridauth's classes
$instance = new Hybridauth([ /* ... */ ]);
```

Comment: I don't get your question, where is this "codeigneter"? And you also have tagged this as CSS, javascript and jquery, where is the css and jquery code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Social Authentication With CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131208/social-authentication-with-codeigniter)